# Adding require old value for checkboxes

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-blade

I have multiple checkboxes that go through validation.. so i need the checkboxes that were picked to remain there..

this are some of them

```
                   <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding-4-tb">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="PHP"> PHP
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding-4-tb">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Python"> Python
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding-4-tb">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Ruby"> Ruby
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding-4-tb">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Rails"> Rails
                    </div>
```

as you can see the value doesn't contain numbers.. so how can i do it ??

Comment: To remain where? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Are you saying that if there is a user error in form submission, you want the form to reappear after failed validation with the previously selected and inputted user information?

Comment: to remain checked in the form

Comment: @justin yes that's what i'm saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear, but I assume you are submitting a form and then rending the form with validation errors, and you don't want to lose the user's selections. If you're just using old-school PHP and HTML in the same file, you would do something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding-4-tb">
    <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="PHP"<?php if(in_array('PHP', $skills))?> checked<?php } ?>> PHP
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding-4-tb">
    <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Python"<?php if(in_array('Python', $skills))?> checked<?php } ?>> Python
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding-4-tb">
    <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Ruby"<?php if(in_array('Ruby', $skills))?> checked<?php } ?>> Ruby
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 padding-4-tb">
    <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="Rails"<?php if(in_array('Rails', $skills))?> checked<?php } ?>> Rails
</div>
```

The net is that you need to add the "checked" attribute to each previously selected checkbox. You determine whether or not each box was selected by checking for the presence of it's value in the array of skills values sent to the server on submit.

Comment: Use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) instead of inline-if if you're just going to echo out a short string. `<?= in_array('Rails', $skills) ? 'checked' : '' ?>`

Comment: Some people think cucumbers taste better pickled. Clarity is preferable to brevity if you are demonstrating a concept.

Comment: I usually separate the logic from the html, which provides additional clarity at the expensive of additional variables. For example, `$isPythonChecked` would be either `= ''` or `= ' checked'` depending on whether the value was in the `$skills` array, which is determined with the rest of the php, not mixed into the form.

Comment: @Justin that's a good idea. I always use a template engine like Smarty or Twig that handles separation of concerns and abstracts this kind of thing away.

Comment: Well your answer was more or less what I was going to say so I upvoted... Might add in a sentence or two about what `checked` is just to improve the distinction between the php vs. html. That is, the game plan here is to see if the value exists (was it selected?), and, if so, to add the html property `checked` to the appropriate `input` tag.